# jQuery, get and set tag values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a

```
<span id="test">5</span>
```

and I wand to get its value, 5. And I want to change that value. how do I realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#test').text(); // Gets
$('#test').text('hello'); // Sets
```

Took about 10 seconds to get into the documentation http://jquery.com and search for "text" and read it...

Answer (score 2):

Get it:

```
$("#test").text();
```

Set it:

```
$("#test").text("New text");
```

Reference: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

To get it, you *probably* want the number, so get the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and parse it with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), like this:

```
var val = parseInt($("#test").text(), 10);
```

To set it just pass the value to [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like this:

```
$("#test").text(newVal);
```

[You cant test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jPtff/).